# Install specific version of Bazel with Bazelisk

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to use Bazel to rebuild Tensorflow with compiler flags, but have been getting errors.

In the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#install_bazel) explaining how to build Tensorflow from the source, they say that Bazelisk will download the correct version for Tensorflow... but when I was getting the errors, I decided to check the Bazel version and it said 4.2.2 (which is the latest version). The [tested builds](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#tested_build_configurations) the Bazel version is only 3.7.2 for 2.7 version of Tensorflow (which is what I am using)...

Is there a way to use Bazelisk to install version 3.7.2? Or do I have to manually download Bazel and add it to the path?

- If so, how do I do it? The way I installed it before was just downloading and running the `.exe` file from the website... and there wasn't any opportunity to enter a version for Bazel...
- If not, how do I uninstall Bazelisk? I tried looking for a way to uninstall, but couldn't find anything...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bazelisk will look in the `WORKSPACE` root for a file named `.bazelversion` (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/.bazelversion)). This file is supposed to contain the Bazel version number you want to use.

There are also other options to tell Bazelisk which version to use: [How does Bazelisk know which Bazel version to run?](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk#how-does-bazelisk-know-which-bazel-version-to-run)

To use for instance Bazel 0.26.1 you can Bazelisk this way:

```
$ USE_BAZEL_VERSION=0.26.1 bazelisk version
```

Comment: Example with `.bazelversion` is good